# Terminal in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I have just installed the latest version of ubuntu in a virtualbox.
Now I need the terminal window, but it is not on the task bar at the left. How can I get it to appear?

Comment: I think this might be more appropriate on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the Ubuntu icon in the upper-left corner.

[image]

You should get a "Search" window.  Type the word "terminal," and it should come up.

[image]

For easy access in the future, you can drag it to the left and into the launcher.

Answer (score 1):

Press Alt+F2 type "Gnome-Terminal".

To get the same in future, you can drag it to the left and into the launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Ubuntu symbol in the upper left and type "term" in the search box. It will auto-complete and show you the terminal icon. Click to run it. Then you can right-click on it in the task bar to lock it there.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + Alt + T.
It's the default shortcut key.